# How do you draw text in the correct area (taking into account stylesheets) in Qt?

Tags: c++, c, qt

I am trying to elide text in a `QLabel` (subclassed into Label). The problem is that the custom `paintEvent()` doesn't respect the variables set by the stylesheet (especially padding/margin). How do I fix this?

As you can see I have one solution which does mostly the right thing, but the margins don't function properly. The other solution is far from working but along the right path. I know that I need to do something with `QStyle` to get the size of the area, but I dont understand it. The documentation is really confusing.

```
void Label::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event){
    if (this->elide == Qt::ElideNone){
        QLabel::paintEvent(event);
        return;
    }

    QPainter p(this);
    QFontMetrics fm(font());
    if (fm.width(text()) > contentsRect().width()) {
        if (1){ //this kind of works...
            QRect rect = this->contentsRect();
            rect.adjust(this->margin(), this->margin(), -this->margin(), -this->margin());
            QString elided_txt = this->fontMetrics().elidedText(text(), this->elide, rect.width(), Qt::TextShowMnemonic); //This is the key line.

            p.drawText(rect(), elided_txt, QTextOption(Qt::AlignVCenter | Qt::AlignLeft));
        } else { //the correct solution should look something like this:


            QStyle *style = this->style();

            QRect rect = style->itemTextRect(fm, this->rect(), Qt::AlignVCenter | Qt::AlignHCenter, true, this->text());

            QString elided_txt = this->fontMetrics().elidedText(text(), this->elide, rect.width(), Qt::TextShowMnemonic); //This is the key line.

            style->drawItemText(&p, this->rect(), Qt::AlignVCenter | Qt::AlignLeft, this->palette(), true, elided_txt);
        }
    } else {
        QLabel::paintEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem? I have a similar issue, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42636084/how-to-draw-a-qpixmap-at-pos0-0-including-margin-padding-sizes